# Does “on average” Hölder continuity imply Hölder continuity?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth, bounded, connected open subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

A function $f: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is said to be *strongly Hölder continuous on average* of order $\alpha$, for $0 < \alpha < 1$ if there exists some constant $C_\alpha > 0$ such that for almost every $x \in \Omega$, we have

$$\int_{\Omega} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|^{n + \alpha}} \, dy \leq C_\alpha.$$

**Question:** Is it true that if a function is strongly Hölder continuous on average of order $\alpha$, then it admits a modification that is classically Hölder continuous of order $\alpha$?